# How to proceed further in Ubuntu Core after configuration?

Tags: ssh, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-core

I have installed Ubuntu Core on KVM using [This link](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/kvm)

And I have also added the SSH keys on my Ubuntu SSO account. And now this screen is shown:
[The screenshot after the configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6elq.png)

But how do I proceed further? everytime I restart the VM this window is shown.

Answer (score 0):

To proceed further follow steps below:

1.The screenshot in question says that Ubuntu Core is running on the VM. 
2. Then open a new terminal window and login to system by using command:    `ssh <Ubuntu SSO account name>@localhost`
3. After this you would have logged in successfully.